# Angular 7 - Loading Parent Component After all individual child component are ready with data

Tags: angular, components

I am bit confused about the exact way to frame this question, but I will try my best to explain it.I have an Angular 7 application.In that I have a home component and inside the home component template, I have couple of other components to render. Below is my home.component.html

```
<div>
<comp-a></comp-b>
<comp-b></comp-b>
<comp-c></comp-c>
</div>
```

Where comp-a, comp-b and comp-c are individual components and depend upon external calls for the data. I have encapsulated them in separate services. Example like

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { compaVM } from "../models/compaVM";
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CompAService {

compalist: compa[] = new Array();

private compaSubject = new Subject<compaVM[]>();

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

compalistObservableListner() {
return this.compaSubject.asObservable();
}

getAllcompa(zoneId) {

this.httpClient.get<{ message: string, data: any }>('http://localhost:3000/api/xxxx/' + zoneId)
.subscribe((resp) => {
this.compalist = resp.data.map((complistdata) => {
return new compaVM(id, name)
});

this.compaSubject.next([...this.compalist]);
})
}
}
```

Likewise I have separate services for comp-b and comp-c. Home component.ts just has ngOnInit() with no code. I am currently using it as sort of Parent for this child components to render.
Currently when I start the application, the home component renders, but comp-a and comp-b does not load together. They data loads after some time.
My question is what should be the approach or rather how can I make my parent component wait to render until all my child components are ready and I can shown them in one go.
The child components don't have individual routes. They are shown on home component html hence I have just one route defined like

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
path: '', component: HomeComponent
}
];
```

Help appreciated !!
Thanks

Comment: One thing you could do is set your child component to display none <comp-a [style.display]="show"></comp-b>. Initially set show to 'none'. Once child component has loaded data, emit an event and in parent set show  = 'visible'

Comment: You could set parents display to none (for now), and have a fancy way of communication using EventEmitter. In each of your child components, emit an event after data is gathered. Listen for those emits in your parent component, and change a component property every time (lets say a counter). Set a conditional display of parent component (if counter is some value, display, if not, don't).
If you don't find any smoother solution, I can guide you through whole process